# Return SQL value based on condition

Tags: sql, ms-access

Trying to get my head around this but I am stumped. Can I use an IIf with a HAVING statement or a CASE?

My current SQL is this:

```
    SELECT dbo_forecast.mtl_part_part_nbr,
       SUM(Round(dbo_forecast.forecast_qty)) AS FCST,
       dbo_m8stacd_standards.whse_nbr,
       dbo_m8stacd_standards.statn_cd,
       dbo_m8stacd_standards.prty
INTO   tblforecast77
FROM   dbo_m8stacd_standards
       INNER JOIN dbo_forecast
               ON dbo_m8stacd_standards.part_nbr =
                  dbo_forecast.mtl_part_part_nbr
WHERE  ( ( ( dbo_forecast.type ) = 11
            OR ( dbo_forecast.type ) = 12 )
         AND ( ( dbo_forecast.forecast_month ) = '01'
                OR ( dbo_forecast.forecast_month ) = '02'
                OR ( dbo_forecast.forecast_month ) = '03'
                OR ( dbo_forecast.forecast_month ) = '04'
                OR ( dbo_forecast.forecast_month ) = '05'
                OR ( dbo_forecast.forecast_month ) = '06'
                OR ( dbo_forecast.forecast_month ) = '07'
                OR ( dbo_forecast.forecast_month ) = '08'
                OR ( dbo_forecast.forecast_month ) = '09'
                OR ( dbo_forecast.forecast_month ) = '10'
                OR ( dbo_forecast.forecast_month ) = '11'
                OR ( dbo_forecast.forecast_month ) = '12' ) )
GROUP  BY dbo_forecast.mtl_part_part_nbr,
          dbo_m8stacd_standards.whse_nbr,
          dbo_m8stacd_standards.statn_cd,
          dbo_m8stacd_standards.prty
HAVING ( ( ( dbo_forecast.mtl_part_part_nbr ) = "00104918" )
         AND ( ( dbo_m8stacd_standards.whse_nbr ) = 77 )
         AND ( ( dbo_m8stacd_standards.prty ) = "01"
                OR ( dbo_m8stacd_standards.prty ) = "d" )
         AND ( ( SUM(Round([dbo_forecast].[forecast_qty])) ) > 0 ) );
```

And returns this:

[image]

What I want to return is if there is a "D" in prty (for that part number) return the FCST for that, if there is not a prty (for that part number) D return the FCST for prty = "01"

edit: Sorry I should have worded this better. What I want is return one record. The prty=d record if it exists, otherwise the 01 record.

Comment: untested:  `SELECT IIF(prty='D',FCST,prty)  FROM ...`   or `SELECT CASE WHEN prty='D' then FCST else prty END FROM ....`

Comment: Sorry I should have worded this better.  What I want is retrun one record.  The prty=d record if it exists, otherwise the 01 record.

Comment: again untested: `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table WHERE prty in ('D','01') ORDER BY CASE WHEN prty='D' then 1 when prty='01 then 2 end `   (P.S. untested because I do not like ms-access, because ...(my opinion.... )), But selecting the 'D' and the '01' records, doing a correct ORDER BY, and LIMITING the output to the first row should do it.

Comment: MSAccess SQL does not suport CASE, try IIf(). Or build a pass-through query if backend is SQLServer. If you want one record for each part, that calls for a correlated subquery. If you want to filter before aggregation, use WHERE clause.